# Which one uses two prepositions correctly? "information about and history of Thailand" or "information about Thailand and history of Thailand."

Tags: prepositions

Example

> I need basic information **about** and history **of** Thailand.

or

> I need basic information **about** Thailand and history **of** Thailand.

Which one is the best sentence?

I apologize if my examples are not good enough.

Comment: Why do you say that there are 'phrasal verbs' in your sentence? I can't see any.

Comment: You have no phrasal verbs in  either sentence.

Comment: aw sorry guy, I get confused because phrasal verbs contain preposition to. TT'

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is ungrammatical. You're essentially trying to combine "about X" and "about Y" and the correct construct for that is "about X and Y".

Your second example, if you add the missing article (i.e. it should be "...and *the* history of Thailand") is grammatically correct.

However, the best answer really is:

> I need basic information about Thailand and its history.

This avoids repeating "Thailand" twice and therefore sounds better.

---

This answer is based off me being a native speaker of American English, but this information can also be verified with corpora, such as [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). A search for "information about and" only brings up hits for a different parallel structure (for example something like "information about and links to tools").

Comment: This answer assumes that the two things the writer wants are (1) information about Thailand and (2) information about the history of Thailand. A likely interpretation of both the proposed sentences, though, is that the writer wants (1) information about Thailand and (2) history of Thailand.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best phrasing would be: “I need basic infirmation about, and the history of, Thailand”. It’s a bit awkward to the English-speaking ear, but I think it’s the best choice if you want that word order.

Comment: Why on earth would you want that word order?